# How to sort files numerically?

Tags: windows-xp

win xp sp3 - windows explorer

How can I sort files by their numerical values.
For example:

```
1.jpg  
2.jpg.  
...  
...  
11.jpg  
12.jpg
```

Comment: as far as I know you cant.  Explorer sorts by alphabetically by string.  11 comes before 2, because the first 1 in 11 is lower than 2.

Comment: What you're describing is the default behavior: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YJl9C.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NTFS file system used also in Windows XP stores the files in a binary tree. The files are always sorted in the directory. When you choose the file name column in the Windows explorer you get the order of the files in the file system. Only choosing other sort criteria like modification date is done in explorer.

Unfortunately you can't change the file system order with Windows explorer and your request can't be fulfilled.

Comment: harper, my request is not to travel on Moon with next Apollo! My request is to sort the files according their num. values. Win OS costs lot of money. It should be one click job. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: "My request is to sort the files according their num. values." -> "Unfortunately you can't change ... order"